# how to show images in react using a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, image

i have this array of objects i am looping through to display its data, however when i am using the img tag in the loop, images won't show

i have tried using react-image, doesn't render obviously. i realized that if the src is a path instead of a link, image doesn't show, it only shows if the src was a link

```
// App.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { projects } from './myData';
import Img from "react-image";

class App extends Component {
  render(){
            return (
              <div className="App">

                {projects.map(p => {

                  return <img key={p.id} src={p.src} alt="can't show image" />;
                })}
              </div>
            );
          }
}

export default App;

// myData.js
export const projects = [
         {
           id: 1,
           name: "Tic Tac Toe game",
           src: "http://www.m9c.net/uploads/15682238971.gif"
         },
         {
           id: 2,
           name: "Tic Tac Toe game",
           src: "./images/tictactoe.gif"
         }
       ];
```

i wanna be able to use local path to show the images, my whole project doesn't communicate with a server an i don't need it to.

Comment: So when you look at this app, what does it say in the browser's address bar? I.e. where and how is it hosted?

Comment: @ChrisG i'm still working locally

Comment: What does that mean? What does it say in the address bar? Is the URL starting with `file:///`? Are you building using webpack? create-react-app? Did you put the images in the public folder?

Comment: Are you using webpack ? You might need a file-loader or make sure your images are in your public folder

Comment: @ChrisG it's (http://localhost:3000/), using create-react-app

Comment: i had the photo placed in the public folder now, altered the path and it works!
to be honest i'm a beginner and this hasn't cross my mind before, although i asked around before posting here ^^, thanks anyway!

Comment: You can in theory import the files in your scripts and reference them that way, in that case they get built along with the scripts. But putting them in public will also work, if you always run and never build.

Answer (score 1):

Your source is looking at `{props.src}` instead of `{p.src}`

```js
   <div className="App">
    {projects.map(p => {
      return <img key={p.id} src={p.src} alt="can't show image" />;
    })}
   </div>
```

Comment: Well spotted, however OP's code would cause an error and they wouldn't see *any* images, so we can assume this error isn't in their actual code.

Comment: you're right, fixed it, that was just a copy paste problem. i tried using different component but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think taht maybe the problem can be related to the path to the image, because the implementation it's good, but maybe try another approach.

This is a sample of how load a local image in the same folder.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png'; // Tell Webpack this JS file uses this image

console.log(logo); // /logo.84287d09.png

function Header() {
  // Import result is the URL of your image
  return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue, but I managed to resolve it using the following code. Please note that I'm currently using React with TypeScript. I hope this code can provide you with some guidance in solving your own issue.

This is the method I used to concatenate the pathname of my image. It's important to note that I utilized the **require** function, which effectively resolved the problem I was facing.

```
const findProductImage = (path: string) => {
    const result = path.slice(8);
    return require(`../images/${result}`);
}
```

in my html

```
<Box m="auto" sx={{ position: "relative", width: {md:"100%", xs:"80%"} }}>          
     {data.map((item) => (
         <Stack key={item._id} direction="row" spacing={2} sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
              <img src={findProductImage(item.imagePath)} alt="image" width="100%" height="100%" />
         </Stack>
      ))}        
</Box>
```